# How to properly tesselate a image of cells using matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, cells, tesselation

I have the following picture which is a photo of pancreatic cells [image]

What I would like to do is being able to get the membrane of each cell (red filament) and then do a tessellation in order to get an idea of the length of a filament.
So far I have tried to use the example given on the matlab website but the result is not really good...

```
 I = imread('picture.tiff');
 I_gray = rgb2gray(I);
 [~, threshold] = edge(I_gray, 'sobel');
 fudgeFactor = .5;
 BWs = edge(I_gray,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
 se90 = strel('line', 3, 90);
 se0 = strel('line', 3, 0);
 BWsdil = imdilate(BWs, [se90 se0]);
```

[image]

I have been searching for hours other way to do it but without any satisfying result... Is there a way to do so ? Maybe an other software than matlab could be more efficient. Thank you by advance !

Comment: For hours?! only *for hours*? So, you want to implement a research level method to automatically segment cells and you searched *hours*?  I mean, people do 4 years of a PhD to do this things properly. Your first step should be an image processing book/course.

Comment: The filament seems pretty red, I'd try to exploit this information if I were you.

Comment: I understand that is complex, I won't give my personal situation but this project I am working on is a side project part of my PhD (I am physicist, not biologist) and I do not have a lot of time to dedicate to. I am trying to use the fact that the filament are pretty red but it never ends that well...

Comment: Now I don't have time to experiment, but if you haven't done it you could try to check the Hue channel after having converted the image from RGB to HSV with `rgb2hsv`. The hue channel is illumination invariant, so the red filament should be pretty much uniform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about cells or tessellation or whatever.  But if you want to detect those blobs in a non uniform background, then I might help. You need to analyse the blobs individually because of the non uniform background. You can't just set a fixed threshold to detect all blobs at once. First, you will detect each blob individually and then use individual threshold. Here is the example

The original image

```
im=imread('gxGkH.jpg');
figure,imagesc(im);axis image;
```

[image]

I am choosing only the blue colour to analyse

```
imb=im(:,:,3);
figure,imagesc(imb);axis image;
```

[image]

1) Blur the image, since after blurring the blobs will have local
maxima/minima at their centres

```
sigma=7;
kernel = fspecial('gaussian',4*sigma+1,sigma);
im2=imfilter(imb,kernel,'symmetric');

figure,imagesc(im2);axis image;
```

[image]

2) Use watershed transform to separate each blob region

```
% L = watershed(im2);
L = watershed(max(im2(:))-im2);
[x,y]=find(L==0);
```

Draw the boundaries

```
figure,imagesc(im2),axis image
hold on, plot(y,x,'r.')
```

[image]

3) Here I analyse each blob individually and find an otsu threshold for
each blob, then I detect the blobs and combine all detections

```
tmp=zeros(size(imb));

for i=1:max(L(:))
  ind=find(L==i);
  mask=L==i;
  [thr,metric] =multithresh(imb(ind),1);
  if metric>0.7
    tmp(ind)=imb(ind)>thr;
  end
end
```

Remove some noise

```
tmp=imopen(tmp,strel('disk',1));
figure,imagesc(tmp),axis image
```

[image]

If the background has higher contrast then the blobs, then you won't need to invert the image in watershed transform.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this may get you closer to the solution of your problem, but what I would do would be something like this. Mind you, it's a really simple and naive approach:

```
image = imread('picture.tiff'); % load image
image = rgb2hsv(image); % convert to hsv colorspace
image = image(:,:,1); % take the hue channel

binary_im = imbinarize(image); % make binary image
```

The binary image should look like this:

[image]

Now you can use Mathematical Morphology to eliminate the noise. You first create a structuring element and then you convolve it with the binary image:

```
str_el = strel('disk', 5, 0); % create a round, 5px radius, str_el
closed_im = imclose(binary_im, str_el); % close image with str_el
```

Now your new image should look like this:

[image]

At this point you can use another morphological operation that finds the skeleton:

```
skeleton = bwmorph(closed_im, 'skel', Inf); % Find skeleton image
```

The skeleton image would look like this:

[image]

Of course this method is far from being precise, but may give you an overall information on the length of the filament, especially if you could get rid of the final noise (those appendices of the skeleton).

Comment: It is not precise indeed but since I can repeat the treatment for a large set of image it could be enough. I'll work on this ! Thank you very much !