# Cannot count object because they are too close, can I count missing object?

Tags: python, opencv, object, detection

For a project, I'm trying to count objects on an image.
For the most part, I'm successful as objects are at least a little bit separated from each others.

For other portions, no morphological transformations seems to work

I'm now thinking of counting 'missing objects' : ie

**source image**

[image]

Idea : as all object are roughly the same size, maybe I could use an 'image template' 
(or some kind of np kernel)

[image]

by calculating the size of 'holes' I could calculate the num of templates that could fit ?

Any thoughts or ideas to spare ?

Comment: can you post the code of what you have done

Comment: Try this solution, it is the same problem with a different image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374463/matlab-segmentation-to-separate-touching-objects-in-an-image/42891793#42891793

Comment: Compute mean number of green pixels per object and estimate num of objects by counting pixels. May be not very accurate, but simple way.